# Kotlin for Android: OnItem Selected Listener

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I am developing an android project with Kotlin

I would like to get values of x and y outside listener and print the multiplication value on textview gpa1 but they are unchanged

```
class sem1gpaactivity : AppCompatActivity(){
var x:Int=0
var y:Double=0.0
var z:Double=0.0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.sem1gpa)
val firstterm01 = arrayOf("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8")


val spinner = findViewById<View>(R.id.spinnerfirsttermh1) as Spinner
val spinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, firstterm01)

spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
  (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item) // The drop down view
spinner.adapter = spinnerArrayAdapter
spinner.spinnerfirsttermh1!!.onItemSelectedListener = object : 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
   override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: 
Long) {

      when (p2){

          0->  x=0
          1->  x=1
          2->  x=2
          3->  x=3
          4->  x=4
          5->  x=5
          6->  x=6
          7->  x=7
          8->  x=8

      }

   }

    override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {}
}

val firstterm02 = arrayOf("A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D+", "D", "F")
val spinner1 = findViewById<View>(R.id.spinnerfirsttermh11) as Spinner
val spinnerArrayAdapter1 = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, firstterm02)
spinnerArrayAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item) // The drop down view
spinner1.adapter = spinnerArrayAdapter1
spinner1.spinnerfirsttermh11!!.onItemSelectedListener = object : 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, 
p3: Long) {
        val spinnerLanguage2 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString()
        when (p2){
            0->  y=4.0
            1->  y=3.7
            2->  y=3.3
            3->  y=3.0
            4->  y=2.7
            5->  y=2.3
            6->  y=2.0
            7->  y=1.7
            8->  y=1.3
            9->  y=1.0
            10-> y=0.0
        }
                          }
    override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {}
}
z=x*y
gpa1.text = z.toString()
}}
```

z result zero because x and y are not changed and text view show 000
i tried to put textiew code in the fun in listener of first spinner and show only x it work but when i put textview code outside listener it show nothing

Answer (score 0):

the text will not change like this because the app excute oncreate method only one time when the activity first created unless you destroy the activity and create it again , so you can do this by changing your gpa1 text inside the both spinner listener , like that :

**in the fist spinner listener**

```
spinner.spinnerfirsttermh1!!.onItemSelectedListener = object :
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3:
        Long) {

            when (p2){

                0->  x=0
                1->  x=1
                2->  x=2
                3->  x=3
                4->  x=4
                5->  x=5
                6->  x=6
                7->  x=7
                8->  x=8

            }
            z=x*y
            tv.text = z.toString()

        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {}
    }
```

**in the second spinner listener**

```
spinner1.spinnerfirsttermh11!!.onItemSelectedListener = object :
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int,
                                    p3: Long) {
            val spinnerLanguage2 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString()
            when (p2){
                0->  y=4.0
                1->  y=3.7
                2->  y=3.3
                3->  y=3.0
                4->  y=2.7
                5->  y=2.3
                6->  y=2.0
                7->  y=1.7
                8->  y=1.3
                9->  y=1.0
                10-> y=0.0
            }
            z=x*y
            tv.text = z.toString()
        }
        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {}
    }
```

Comment: thank it works , is there any way to save the value of z outside the listener in another public variable which we can use outside the listener???